# WEATHER-resistant GFCI's required in bathrooms?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, kitchens, gfci

My new non-WR GFCI outlet says on the back of it...

> NOTICE:DO NOT INSTALL non-weather resistant devices in wet or damp locations as per latest NEC code. When installing weather resistant devices in wet locations use with approved weather resistant covers/enclosures, caulk and gaskets.

Does this mean that WEATHER-resistant (WR) GFCI's must now be installed in INDOOR damp locations (bathrooms, kitchens) as per the "latest NEC code"?

Comment: Related --> https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/69044/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-a-weather-resistant-gfci-in-a-bathroom

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Device instructions do not have any standing to decide what NEC does or does not say.

However, device instructions *can*, and *do*, make declarations about how the device itself may be used.  And these have the force of law.

> **NEC 110.3(B)  Installation and Use.** Listed or labeled equipment shall be installed and used in accordance with any instructions included in the listing or labeling.

The instructions you quote, clearly defer to NEC as to the definition of "wet locations".

> **100.1**
>
> **Location, Damp.** Locations protected from weather and not subject to saturation with water or other liquids but subject to moderate degrees of moisture. Examples of such locations include partially protected locations under canopies, marquees, roofed open porches, and like locations, and interior locations subject to moderate degrees of moisture, such as some basements, some barns, and some cold-storage warehouses.
>
> **Location, Wet.** Installations underground or in concrete slabs or masonry in direct contact with the earth; in locations subject to saturation with water or other liquids, such as vehicle washing areas; and in unprotected locations exposed to weather.

Comment: So the answer to the title is "No".

Comment: Maybe not.  I forgot "damp" and that seems like a wobbler.  Mind you I'm quoting NEC 2011, something could've changed.

Comment: Code has slightly changed but indoor locations (other than tub and shower) in a residence are considered dry.

Comment: Considering how damp my bathroom gets after a nice long shower (thanks tankless heater!) I wonder what they are thinking.

Comment: I agree with Harper that the regulation regarding "damp" is indeed a "wobbler"(unclear). I installed the non-WR GFCI per Ed Beal's advice, but after reading Harper's comment about his "nice long showers", I concluded that I should replace that with a WR-GFCI. Therefore I gave the nod to Harper, despite having already followed Ed Beal's advice. I thank you both for answering my question.

Answer (score 11):

The walls of your bathroom are considered dry locations as are most indoor spaces. A standard GFCI is correct for your needs. Out door locations that are not protected are wet / damp locations.

Comment: While I appreciate Harpers thorough answer, he doesn't actually directly answer the question. This seems to be the correct answer to me, while people may choose to use WR-GFCI indoors, I do not believe it is required.